# Excel returns HRESULT: 0x800A03EC when the program is run by service (otherwise OK)

Tags: c#, excel, csv, com, windows-services

I have a Windows application that reads from a file and writes the contents into an Excel file. I have two modes of running this program. One is when the user is present and presses a button to generate the Excel file. And the program works fine in this mode. The other mode is when user schedules this job to be run by a Windows Service. And that is where I am getting the exception `HRESULT: 0x800A03EC`. Both these modes use the exact same code.

Please note that I do the exact procedure with `.csv` files and they work in both modes. `.csv` files do not use any `COM` components to be created and maybe that is why they can be done successfully.

This is the code for creating my Excel file.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = null;
Workbook workbook = null;
Worksheet worksheet = null;
xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(1);
worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1];
int columnCount = dt.Columns.Count;
int rowCount = dt.Rows.Count;
// Write header row
for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++)
{
    worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dt.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
}
// The rest
int lastIndex = 0;
for (int j = 1; j <= rowCount; j++)
{
    for (int k = 1; k <= columnCount; k++)
        worksheet.Cells[j + 1, k] = dt.Rows[j - 1][k - 1];
    lastIndex = j + 1;
}
string path = string.Format("{0}\\{1}.xlsx", campaignOutputPath, campaignFileName);
if (File.Exists(path))
    File.Delete(path);

xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(path, XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared, false, false, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
workbook.Close();
xlApp.Quit();
```

Is it because creating a new Excel application cannot be done in the background? Because after a while of running this function in the background by the service, Windows shows me the following error:

[image]

Comment: Be aware that using Excel in a non-interactive session (such as a service) is unsupported, extremely fragile, and quite possibly a violation of the MS Office license agreement. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Comment: @EuroMicelli I honestly was unaware of that.

Comment: Is your windows service being run in the context of the user who has installed Excel? The account where your application runs normally? Please specify that account on the [Log On tab of the service's properties](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#AppNotWorkingFromService).

Comment: @CoreTech The Excel came comes from our parent company so probably not. But what Euro Micelli said made sense so I made it disable to be run by the service for now.